# Add ListView item from Top using CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I have created a `ListView` with its value from the `CursorAdapter` .I am Successfully able to append the value to the Bottom of the List.

Now , How would I append  the Value to `ListView` from  top position

I know if I use `ArrayAdapter` or BaseAdapter I could b possible using `add(postion , adapter)`
easily.

I want to know how could we do it using `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: the data come from the cursor. if you are adding something, it has to be in the cursor (probably in the database, therefore). (unless you mean a header of some sort)?

Comment: @njzk2 you mean I have to suffle my db as per my ListView . And get the content I requiere from it using Cursor and append it to ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CursorAdapter just links the ListView with the Database/Data from the Database specified in the Cursors sqlQuery.

```
String sqlQuery = "Select * From WhatSoEver";

Cursor c = dbhelper.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```

the list will get each Item/Row that the Cursor could find, matching the sql selection. So if you want to add another item, you have to add it to your database. If you dont specify any Order, it will be ordered by id or the order the rows were inserted.

If you want the latest items to show up first, you will have to specify a different order, assuming your table has an id, you could do it like this

```
String sqlQuery = "Select * From WhatSoEver Order By id desc";
Cursor c = dbhelper.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```

Comment: how this gonna appends the item at the top position say zero of ListView

Comment: since you are using a cursoradapter the first item of the cursor is the first item in your list, assuming you added your item to your database.

Comment: I am getting the value from database correctly .No issue over that.Need to know HOW we could append the value to the first position. Is there any method available to do that

Comment: i told you how to do that, the fact that you dont understand the answer, makes me question that you know how the CursorAdapter works :)